# Why is wget much faster than downloading via Chrome?

Tags: 14.04, networking

I tried to download a gigabyted file where I got 200~300 kb/s in my browser but the same link worked in wget over 6MB/s...Is there some magic behind the command?

Comment: Nope, `wget` is pretty plain. No parallel file chunk downloads or similar stuff. I have no real idea, why this happened, but I might get some, if you provide an example link, that exhibits your issue.

Comment: Is it possible that this is related to `user-agent` and the server is handling browser and wget connections differently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

wget normally works a little bit faster than Chrome because it's a terminal program so there is less resource usage overhead, but that would not explain such a large difference in download speeds between wget and Chrome. You probably have an issue with downloading that large file in Chrome. wget is a better tool than Chrome for downloading large files, if you don't have to solve a captcha in order to download the file.

Comment: Good one!  Chrome is a complex piece of software and does lots of things well, some things good and some badly...  `wget` does one thing and one thing only and extremely well!  ;-)  (Upvoted!)  P.S. No one downloads multi-gigabyte files any more: you torrent them...  :P  >:)

Comment: I have the exact opposite. Using the terminal `apt-get`, I got an average of 80kb/s, but when I tried the download in Chrome, I got 3mb/s. Do you know why?

Comment: It could be because different download servers are selected by wget and Chrome.

Answer (score 5):

The discrepancies in speed that you are seeing can easily be explained by variable server load. Although **I have seen high rates of throughput with wget**, I've also seen relatively low rates. However, I've never seen a discrepancy in speed of the magnitude you mention, so I'm certain there is another variable that you are not considering. My experience tells me that the load on the server or network segment(s) you were using was higher when you got the lower rates and lower when  you got the higher ones. **This assumes that the tests were done on the same hardware using the same network interface.** Different hardware can provide **huge** discrepancies in results. For example, you'll never get anywhere near the throughput on a netbook with a 100Mbps interface (or WiFi) that you'll get from a well built desktop with a Gigabit interface. Real world tests prove that properly designed and built hardware can provide throughput 30 times or more throughput off the same server on the same network segment. There are more variables involved than one might think. The speed of the storage media, the network interface, the bus(FSB) and even the RAM speed can have an impact on throughput. As others have mentioned the software itself CAN impact the speed of transmission, but the difference is usually minimal in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was attempting to download android studio for windows (1.1GB).  After about 1 minute of downloading chrome was reporting 18min to go.

I cancelled that download, logged onto my debian box and used wget, which pulled it in 1m55s.

**My laptop is over wifi however, the debian box is hard wired to the router.**

Comment: For the comparison to be fair, the network interface should use the same kind (either WiFi or Ethernet cable). Else, the download speed might be affected by the performance of hardware.

Comment: @clearkimura totally agree, however the accepted answer points out the discrepancy should not be considerable, so this answer points out a reason why it could be